# Form - previous selected value in dropdown posts to email

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created a new form. Although the onchange "systemUpdate" appears to work  OK, after submitting the form it posts to email, and the email shows previous selected option values, that were changed and updated prior to submitting the form.

For example, user selects selectedIndex == 1, and option value "PS/2 connections" (#Wyse_Terminal div), and then changes their mind and selects selectedIndex == 2 and submits, "PS/2 connections" still shows in the email.

How do I go about clearing previous selected option values so that they do not end up in the email? There is a reasonable amount of code, so have just included relevant script and html

```
function systemUpdate(detail) {
if (detail.selectedIndex == 0) {
    $("#Option_Terminal").hide();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").hide();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#HP_Terminal").hide();
    $("#HP_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
} else if (detail.selectedIndex == 1) {
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").show();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").addClass("required");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").show();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").addClass("required");
    $("#HP_Terminal").hide();
    $("#HP_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
} else if (detail.selectedIndex == 2) {
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").hide();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").show();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").addClass("required");
    $("#HP_Terminal").hide();
    $("#HP_Terminal input").removeAttr("class");
} else if (detail.selectedIndex == 3) {
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").hide();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").hide();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#HP_Terminal").show();
    $("#HP_Terminal select").addClass("required");
}}

<form method="POST" title="myForm" id="myForm" name="myForm" action="emailTemplate.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Your System</legend>
    <p><label>Please select your system</label>
        <select id="select_system" name="select_system" class="required" onchange="systemUpdate(this);">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Wyse Terminal">Wyse Terminal</option>
            <option value="Laptop/Desktop">Laptop/Desktop</option>
            <option value="HP Terminal">HP Terminal</option>
        </select> *
    <p><img style="width: 611px;"src="images/systemtype.jpg"/></p>
    </p>
<br />
<div id="Wyse_Terminal">
    <p><label>Please select connection type</legend>
        <select id="Connection_Type" name="Connection_Type" class="required">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="PS/2 connections">PS/2 connections</option>
            <option value="USB connections">USB connections</option>
        </select> *
    <p><img style="width: 611px;"src="images/mouse.png"/></p>
    </p>
</div>
<br />
<div id="Wyse_LaptopDesktop">
    <p><label>Select items required</label>
        <select id="Items_Required" name="Items_Required" class="required">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Keyboard and Mouse ($60)">Keyboard and Mouse ($60)</option>
            <option value="Keyboard only ($40)">Keyboard only ($40)</option>
            <option value="Mouse only ($20)">Mouse only ($20)</option>
        </select> * 
    </p>
</div>
<div id="HP_Terminal">
    <p><label>If HP Terminal</label>
        <select id="HPTerminal" name="HPTerminal" class="required">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Wireless Keyboard and Mouse ($60)">Wireless Keyboard and Mouse ($60)</option>
        </select> *
    </p>
</div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="yourDetails">

</fieldset>

<p class="submit"><input class="button" onClick="return checkTicked();" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
```

Thanks for helping out a newbie!

Comment: long lines of code... please use `.removeClass()` instead of `.removeAttr()`.

Comment: Thanks CJ - should have said, I had originally used .removeClass() and  had the same issue.

Comment: did you closing form with `</form>` ?

Comment: Yout hide `$("#Wyse_Terminal")` but you don't remove the value. Try `$("#Wyse_Terminal").val("")` in `2`

Comment: I tested your code in my machine... Its working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function systemUpdate(detail) {
if (detail.selectedIndex == 0) {
    $("#Option_Terminal").hide();
    $("#Option_Terminal").val("");
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").hide();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").val("");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#HP_Terminal").hide();
    $("#HP_Terminal").val("");
    $("#HP_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
} else if (detail.selectedIndex == 1) {
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").show();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").addClass("required");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").show();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").addClass("required");
    $("#HP_Terminal").hide();
    $("#HP_Terminal").val("");
    $("#HP_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
} else if (detail.selectedIndex == 2) {
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").hide();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").val("");
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").show();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").addClass("required");
    $("#HP_Terminal").hide();
    $("#HP_Terminal").val("");
    $("#HP_Terminal input").removeAttr("class");
} else if (detail.selectedIndex == 3) {
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").hide();
    $("#Wyse_Terminal").val("");
    $("#Wyse_Terminal select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").hide();
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop").val("");
    $("#Wyse_LaptopDesktop select").removeAttr("class");
    $("#HP_Terminal").show();
    $("#HP_Terminal select").addClass("required");
}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Got me on the right lines, just had to tweak a little, e.g. $("#Wyse_Terminal select").val("");